# Why can I not find any documentation on form helpers as part of an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I guess when most people have a form, they use the following syntax for the form helpers: `f.select`, but in the very thorough documentation I can not find anything of that. [I only find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) the standalone `select`, why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no such thing. It's [`select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) if you're using it outside a form builder.

Comment: OK, "form builder", I'll remember that term. Google didn't point me at the right direction at all, but you did - thanks.